# $cordovaNativeAudio.stop not working on ios in ionic

Tags: cordova, audio, ionic-framework

This function is not working on IOS in my ionic app. Works fine on android. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: console log?error?

Comment: Hi, I dont get any error, it just doesnt stop the audio. Have you used the $cordovaNativeAudio.stop successfully on an IOS device?

Comment: I tried this:  $cordovaNativeAudio.stop('audio-test').then(function(response){                   
                    alert(response);
                });  . on android the alert pops up an OK message. No alert on IOS

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, I found the answer. I was using  $cordovaNativeAudio.preloadSimple to preload the audio sample. The $cordovaNativeAudio.stop function doesnt work with the simple preload. You need to use  $cordovaNativeAudio.preloadComplex. All working now.